# How to return an array between two array based on a cell value in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with cells A2:D20 as the first array. 
The other array is F2:I20.

What I want to do is to return an array out of the above two at K2:N20 based on the value of D20. If D20 > 100, return the array A2:D20. If not, F2:I20. How to go about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much like you have worded it:

```
=index(if(D20>100, A2:D20, F2:I20))
```

Comment: Ah, that was silly of me! Index could do all of this. Thanks for your help.